# How to change post status in wordpress with python xmlrpc

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to change post status draft to publish but I can't. I use python 3.8 and xmlrpc module.

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts, NewPost, EditPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.users import GetUserInfo
#-------------------------------------------------------#######
client = Client(wp_site+'/xmlrpc.php', wp_us, wp_pw)
posts = client.call(posts.GetPosts({'number': 3, 'post_status': 'drafts'}))
posts == [WordPressPost, WordPressPost, ...]
for x in range(0,20):
        icerik=posts[x]
        title=icerik.title
        link=icerik.link
        image_url=posts[x].struct.get("post_thumbnail").get("link")
        icerik.post_status = 'publish'
        client.call(posts.EditPost(icerik.id, icerik))
```

ERROR CODE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/abdul/Desktop/PY5QT DENEMELERİ/deneme2/sbpins.py", line 59, in <module>
client.call(posts.EditPost(icerik.id, icerik))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'EditPost'
```

SOLUTON:

just running into the same issue and the solution:

post.thumbnail = post.thumbnail['attachment_id'] before EditPost

did in fact fix the problem for me - Thanks!

Comment: You're overwriting imported `posts` from xmlrpc in line 7 to a list of posts, and the error is self explanatory. Try changing your `posts` variable into something else.

Comment: I fix this problem, thanks..